# Fat jar built with Gradle doesn't include libraries

Tags: java, gradle

I'm trying to build a fat jar which would contain all .jar libraries included in 'libraries' folder.

Here is a snapshot of my build.gradle file:

```
group 'MyApp'
version '2.0'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

    compile files('libraries/ojdbc7.jar')
    compile files('libraries/postgresql-42.1.4.jar')
    compile files('libraries/db2jcc.jar')
}

tasks.withType(Jar) {
    destinationDir = file("$rootDir/target")
}

jar {
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'MainLauncher'
    }
    processResources{
        exclude '*'
    }
    archiveName 'myapp.jar'
}
```

All .jar libraries are included into 'libraries' folder located in root of the project.

For some reason my code works fine in IDE, however fails to execute some tasks when run as a standalone .jar file.

When I decompress the jar, I can see all content inside root folder including libraries which fail to be found.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?